# Pandas dataframe to dictionary with value as a list

Tags: python, pandas

We have the following dataframe df,

```
   0   1  2  3
0 'a' 'b' 1  2
1 'a' 'c' 2  4
```

I want output as

```
{('a', 'b'): [1, 2], ('a', 'c'): [2, 4]}
```

How to use .to_dict() to generate the output?

I tried

```
df.set_index([0,1])[[2,3]].to_dict()
```

and get the result

```
{2: {('a', 'b'): 1, ('a', 'c'): 2}, 3: {('a', 'b'): 2, ('a', 'c'): 4}}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After setting the index, take the transpose and then use `to_dict` with `orient='list'`:

```
df.set_index([0,1]).T.to_dict(orient='list')
```

The resulting output:

```
{('a', 'b'): [1, 2], ('a', 'c'): [2, 4]}
```

Comment: This answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{k: v.tolist() for k, v in df.set_index([0, 1]).iterrows()}

{('a', 'b'): [1, 2], ('a', 'c'): [2, 4]}
```